# Office Add-In Validation Testing Environments

Tags: office-js, office-store

Microsoft validation requirements state:

> Add-ins must be compatible with all versions of
>   Internet Explorer 11 and later, and the latest
>   versions of Microsoft Edge, Chrome, Firefox, and
>   Safari (Mac OS).
>
> Add-ins that support iOS must be fully functional
>   on the latest iPad device using the latest iOS
>   operating system.

My add-in works on my end on an iPad running the latest iOS 10.3.2. The validation report I got back from Microsoft says that things aren't working properly on iOS. When I asked what version they are testing on, they said iOS 9.3.5.

The validation report also says that the add-in doesn't work on Mac, but it works on my end using the latest version of macOS. I'm not sure what version Microsoft is testing with, and I'm wondering if they're not testing with the latest version.

My questions are, why is Microsoft testing on something other than the latest iOS when their requirements state to be fully functional on the latest iOS, and what version of macOS / Safari is Microsoft using to test?

Comment: You probably should ask Microsoft Office Submission team directly. Why bother to write the question nobody can answer on other than Microsoft Support? I would suggest to consider MSDN forums instead.

Comment: Their validation report says to post any questions to StackOverflow.

Comment: Hmmm, in this case nothing else you can do, just wait for answer ;) Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

All Office Store validation takes place on the most recent version of iOS and one version prior. If the Team have reported an iOS issue, then the issue would have been repro on the current testing versions, which are 9.3.5, and either 10.3.1 or 10.3.2 (not all devices are updated to 10.3.2 yet, as we realised not all users have updated)

For Mac testing, the current testing OSx are OS X El Capitan ​and ​macOS Sierra, both with Safari 10.1

Comment: Given that the validation requirements only specify support for the latest iOS, can we have our add-in automatically notify users that they need to be on the latest (iOS 10) if they are on iOS <10?

Comment: Yes, this would be acceptable as long as the limitation is called out in the add-in long description (as seen on Store) and the add-in fails gracefully when loaded on iOS <10